# How can I detect if chrome on android is running in full screen (hides the top part) or not?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I have a simple page with a top header of height 'x' and a bottom menu of height 'y'.

What is in between has height: `calc(100vh - sum of x and y)`.
The problem is that on chrome android when browser tab is present my bottom menu is visible about 10%. When the tab is hidden is ok.

My question is how can I detect this event (hide / show tab) or what solution exists for this crap?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you developing a web page or an app that somehow interacts with the browser? Please clarify.

Comment: It is a web page with ember js.

Comment: Seems to be exactly this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403611/chrome-android-height-scroll-issue-with-footers-and-the-address-bar